# Passing stream to other function

Tags: node.js, express, request, busboy

On the frontend I'm uploading the image using FormData

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('avatar', data.file);
return API.post('/uploadImg', formData)
```

On the backend I am using express and have the next function

```
async function uploadImg(req, res) {
    req.pipe(req.busboy)
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        const fstream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join("thestorage",`/image.${mimetype}` ))
        file.pipe(fstream)
        fstream.on('close', async (error, data) => {
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'Image was uploaded'})
        })
    }  
}
```

I want to split the logic on the backend, so *uploadImg function* will only manage the request and the actual file management would be in the separate function. **How do I pass the file stream to other function?**

I've tried so far:

```
async function uploadImg(req, res) {
    await theUpload(req.headers)
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Image was uploaded'})
}

async function theUpload(headers) {
    let bus_boy = new Busboy({headers: headers})
    bus_boy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        const fstream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join("thestorage",`/image.${mimetype}` ))
        file.pipe(fstream)
        fstream.on('close', async (error, data) => {
            console.log('done')
        })
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why do you only give the headers to `theUpload` and not the whole request parameter?

Comment: It seems that there is an error in your variable. You are defining it as `bus_boy` and later referring to it as `busboy`.

Comment: @Moshe Fortgang fixed the misprint there

Comment: @Geshode why should passing the whole request there, can I just use the necessary part?

Comment: Because then you could do it the same way as you did, when it was just one function.